# How to access 'this' in overridden method?

Tags: typescript

I have an abstract class which exposes a method:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    public update(){
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

Which this class inherits from:

```
public class Doo extends Foo {
    public update(){
        super.update();
        const x = this.getValue(); //problem line
    }
}
```

Now, since `update()` is exposed, it's being executed in a different context, and so that `this` on the "problem line" is referencing the calling object, a problem I'd normally solve by declaring `update()` in the abstract parent as an arrow method:

```
public class Foo {
    public update = () => {
       //call this all i want
    }
}
```

However, if I do this, I can no longer call `super()` from the child class. Is there any way to call `super.update()` *and* maintain control over `this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the best thing you can do is create two methods--one for overriding and one for public. Put implementation in the overriding method as you have it but expose a separate method using arrow functions that calls this.otherMethod(). that way you're preserving `this` for the public method and preserving `super` for the implementation.

This is not really a TypeScript issue but a JavaScript one.

Comment: Just when you think you've gotten away from all the evils of VanillaJS, `this` comes back to haunt you... Thanks then, I guess I'll come up with a less elegant solution.

Comment: Agreed, I'm kinda surprised this wasn't fixed when classes were added--some mechanism to auto-bind this to class methods and still make super work. Not sure that can be polyfilled but it does need to get fixed eventually.